# Kindle Library and cloud

Tags: kindle, kindle-cloud-reader

Is there a way to move books that are in my Kindle Library to my Kindle Cloud? I would prefer to not have each book in the actual library.

Comment: what is the distinction between library and cloud?  definition?

Answer (score 1):

If a matter of storage space on some local device, the following from [sharechair](https://sharechair.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/where-are-my-kindle-books-how-to-find-them-and-move-them/) (dated January 21, 2013) may be of interest:

> removing the books from your Kindle or Kindle App does not ‘delete’ them from your life. It only takes the book off of the device .. but it leaves it in the Cloud, so that you can put it back on your device whenever you choose.
>
> When you want to remove a book from your device, just tap and hold it. On a Kindle App, a bubble will pop up that says “Remove from Device”. Go ahead and tap that. The book will be gone from your reader, but it will still be in the Cloud to be downloaded again, whenever you want it.